# How to copy and paste between cygwin's vi/emacs and windows clipboard?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, cygwin, vi

I tried to paste what I copied in windows clipboard into cygwin's vi or emacs, and it doesn't seem to work with yy (vi) or M-w (emacs).

Is there a way to do it? I learned that `/etc/clipboard` has the clipboard data from windows, but I don't know how to get this info in vi or emacs.

Answer (score 4):

At least for vim, the clipboard is the `"*` register.

So, to yank the current line, go `"*yy`, to paste in the contents of the clipboard, go `"*p`, so on and so forth.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @prosseek; Oh. Well, FWIW, it works in both gvim and the version of vim that comes with it - you could consider using those over cygwin's?

Answer (score 3):

Copy text from vim under cygwin, just press `"`key `+`key `y`key in visual mode :

> "+y

Paste text to vim under cygwin, just press `"` key `+`key `p`key in normal mode :

> "+p

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution mentioned in [Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_Windows_clipboard_in_Cygwin_Vim):

```
function! Putclip(type, ...) range
  let sel_save = &selection
  let &selection = "inclusive"
  let reg_save = @@
  if a:type == 'n'
    silent exe a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . "y"
  elseif a:type == 'c'
    silent exe a:1 . "," . a:2 . "y"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"
  endif
  call writefile(split(@@,"\n"), '/dev/clipboard')
  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
endfunction


vnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call Putclip(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call Putclip('n', 1)<CR>
```

just copy these lines to .vimrc and your \y will do the trick, whether you are using vim or your mouse to select texts.
This may not be a problem since you already have access to the clipboard, but /dev/clipboard is available for Cygwin version 1.7.13 and higher.

Comment: this is the right solution. (at least...on windows server 2012r2 cygwin 3.0.1 vim  8.0.1567).

Answer (score 0):

To paste from the clipboard using vi in Cygwin:

```
Press SHIFT-INSERT in insert mode

(this means the insert key by the Delete/Home/End keys)
```

To copy to the clipboard using vi in Cygwin:

```
When you select text with your mouse, it automatically gets copied to the clipboard.

You can paste from the clipboard by pressing the middle mouse button.
```

Also, in some environments where "*yy doesn't work, you can try *"+yy*.

Unfortunately this does *NOT* work in Cygwin.